# Invoke function of JS from Chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have JS function. How can I invoke it from chrome dev tool? there is any way to insert it arguments?

Comment: You type it into the console if it is available from Global Scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type it right here:

[image]

It's the console in the inspector window.